# The screen resolution difference with a retina display

Tags: display, applescript, resolution

I can get the screen resolution of my Macbook pro using the AppleScript code on this site.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866912/applescript-how-to-get-current-display-resolution

```
on getScreenSize()
    -- from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866912/applescript-how-to-get-current-display-resolution
    set resolutions to {}
    repeat with p in paragraphs of ¬
        (do shell script "system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/Resolution:/{ printf \"%s %s\\n\", $2, $4 }'")
        set resolutions to resolutions & {{word 1 of p as number, word 2 of p as number}}
    end repeat
    -- return the last one assuming that it should be the one that is not the Laptop screen
    return item (length of resolutions as integer) of resolutions
end getScreenSize
```

The returned value matches from the information from "About this Mac".

[image]

However, when I get the window size from a debugger, it shows half of the value from the system. I make a window to fill in a screen, and check the bounds of the window.

[image]

This is confusing and problematic as I'm writing AppleScript code that aligns multiple windows using `set bounds` command.

```
set bounds of s to {x1, y1, x2, y2}
```

What makes difference between the display resolution from a system and bounds of a window? Is it just safe to assume that (system resolution)/2 should be used for setting bounds for retina displays?

Answer (score 2):

MacBookPro has an effective resolution that depends on the Scale you setup for the display.

[image]

You need to use the effective resolution in your code. You can get it from this code, but it works only when there are no external montitors.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set screen_resolution to bounds of window of desktop
end tell
```

### Reference

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488126/get-bounds-of-desktop-with-applescript
- http://osxdaily.com/2014/04/14/change-retina-macbook-screen-resolution-more-space/
- http://www.anandtech.com/show/5996/how-the-retina-display-macbook-pro-handles-scaling